# Dockerfile does not run executable

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM rikorose/gcc-cmake

RUN git clone https://github.com/hect1995/UBIMET_Challenge.git

WORKDIR /UBIMET_Challenge

RUN mkdir build

WORKDIR build

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake=3.13.1-1ubuntu3 protobuf-compiler

RUN cmake ..

RUN make

CMD ["./ubimet /UBIMET_Challenge/data/1706221600.29 output.csv"]
```

Even though it says it executes the last line when building it does not (or it does it incorrectly) as if you run last line it should generate 2 files that are not being generated once I check them using:

```
docker run -t -i trial /bin/bash
```

Nevertheless, if I get inside the container and from there I run:

```
./ubimet /UBIMET_Challenge/data/1706221600.29 output.csv
```

It generates the files, so why does it not generate the files while building?

Comment: Both `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` will be executed every time that your container starts. If you want to execute the code only when it is building you should use `RUN` instead. Additionally, as mentioned by [@bolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805305/bolov) you are using the `CMD` with the incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMD` is the default command to run when you start your container. You are overriding 
this by passing `/bin/bash` to `docker run`.

Either change `CMD` to `RUN` (to run your script at build time) or run `docker run` without the trailing command (to run when you start the container).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `CMD` wrong. `CMD` [has 3 forms](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), none of which are what you are using:

> #### CMD
>
> The `CMD` instruction has three forms:
>
> - `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` (exec form, this is the preferred form)
> - `CMD ["param1","param2"]` (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
> - `CMD command param1 param2` (shell form)

You can use `CMD` like this:

```
CMD ["./ubimet", "/UBIMET_Challenge/data/1706221600.29", "output.csv"]
```